# Find a function $f\geq 0$ such that $e^{-t[(x-\partial_x)\partial_x]^2} f$ is not non-negative for some $t\geq 0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-chains

Consider the square of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator $$A=[(x-\partial_x)\partial_x]^2=(x-\partial_x)\partial_x (x-\partial_x)\partial_x.$$ We know that $[(x-\partial_x)\partial_x]^2$ cannot be a Markov semi-group generator (by the Hille-Yoshida theorem). However, in my understanding, that must imply that $e^{-t[(x-\partial_x)\partial_x]^2}$ is not positivity-preserving. That is because if $e^{-tA}$ maps identity to identity and is positivity-preserving, then $A$ is a Markov semi-group generator.

I have tried to find a function $f\geq 0$ such that $e^{-t[(x-\partial_x)\partial_x]^2} f$ is non-positive, but without success. Any help with this would be great.